# Python, tuple arguments playing nicely with others

Tags: python, arguments, tuples, typeerror

For example:

```
mytuple = ("Hello","World")
def printstuff(one,two,three):
    print one,two,three

printstuff(mytuple," How are you")
```

This naturally crashes out with a TypeError because I'm only giving it two arguments when it expects three.

Is there a simple way of effectively 'splitting' a tuple in a tider way than expanding everything? Like:

```
printstuff(mytuple[0],mytuple[1]," How are you")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not without changing the argument ordering or switching to named parameters.

Here's the named parameters alternative.

```
printstuff( *mytuple, three=" How are you" )
```

Here's the switch-the-order alternative.

```
def printstuff( three, one, two ):
    print one, two, three

printstuff( " How are you", *mytuple )
```

Which may be pretty terrible.

Answer (score 6):

Kinda,... you can do this:

```
>>> def fun(a, b, c):
...     print(a, b, c)
...
>>> fun(*(1, 2), 3)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression
>>> fun(*(1, 2), c=3)
1 2 3
```

As you can see, you can do what you want pretty much as long as you qualify any argument coming after it with its name.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
printstuff(*(mytuple[0:2]+(" how are you",)))
```

Comment: To match the arity in the original example.

Comment: But `mytuple` is already a 2-tuple. So you're slicing a 2-tuple (effectively copying it) for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 1):

```
mytuple = ("Hello","World")

def targs(tuple, *args):
    return tuple + args

def printstuff(one,two,three):
    print one,two,three 

printstuff(*targs(mytuple, " How are you"))
Hello World  How are you
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
def printstuff(*args):
    print args
```

Another option is to use the new [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) collections type.

Comment: But `args` would be (("hello","world)," how are you") as tuple and string.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is possible to do it without changing the order of the arguments. First you have to transform your string to a tuple, add it to your tuple `mytuple` and then pass your larger tuple as argument.

```
printstuff(*(mytuple+(" How are you",)))
# With your example, it returns: "Hello World  How are you"
```